# dynamic formula autofill vba won't adjust

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, rank

```
Range("AQ3").Formula = "=IF(ISNA(RANK(N3,N3:N" & lastRow & ",0)),"""",COUNTIF(N3:N" & lastRow & ", "">$N3"")+1)<=10"
Range("AQ3:AQ" & lastRow).filldown
```

Hi,  I am trying to use rank function in my vba like this but this would just fill the values of the first cell while not dynamically adjusting the range that is entered as N3:N "& lastrow &". This would check if a value in N3 with the list of values from N3 to the last row and give me the ranks. And it will do the same for AQ4, AQ5, etc. however, this code doesnt give me what I want. Can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let Excel worry about the adjustments

```
Range("AQ3:AQ" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(ISNA(RANK(N3,N3:N" & lastRow & ",0)),"""",COUNTIF(N3:N" & lastRow & ", "">$N3"")+1)<=10"
```

Excel will take care of changing **N3...** to **N4...** etc. itself.